# Get array item whose key has a specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm using the TMDb API on a project of mine. When queried for the crew of a movie or tv show, the api returns arrays such as this one:

```
[crew] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
       [credit_id] => 52542287760ee31328001b69
       [department] => Production
       [id] => 5162
       [name] => Mark Johnson
       [job] => Executive Producer
       [profile_path] => /yKGF6cbzyP03Gl1QhVLCu1gWSW6.jpg )

    [1] => Array (
       [credit_id] => 52542288760ee31328001b83
       [department] => Production
       [id] => 29779
       [name] => Michelle MacLaren
       [job] => Executive Producer
       [profile_path] => )

    [2] => Array (
       [credit_id] => 52542287760ee31328001af1
       [department] => Production
       [id] => 66633
       [name] => Vince Gilligan
       [job] => Executive Producer
       [profile_path] => /wSTvJGz7QbJf1HK2Mv1Cev6W9TV.jpg )

    [3] => Array (
       [credit_id] => 52b7008819c29559eb03dd72
       [department] => Sound
       [id] => 1280070
       [name] => Dave Porter
       [job] => Original Music Composer
       [profile_path] => )

)
```

My question is: How can I get all the indexes of the items whose key [job] has the value "Executive Producer"? In other words, how could I echo the names of all the Executive producers?

Thanks!

Comment: A simple `foreach` could do the job. `foreach ($array as $sub) { if ($sub['job'] == 'Execute Producer') { echo $sub['name']; } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter array

```
$crew = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Mark',
        'job' => 'Executive Producer'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Johnny',
        'job' => 'Original Music Composer'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Mark',
        'job' => 'Executive Producer'
    ),
);


$executiveProducters = array_filter($crew, function ($array) {
    return $array['job'] == 'Executive Producer';
});
```

Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [job] => Executive Producer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [job] => Executive Producer
        )

)
```

Display names

```
foreach($executiveProducters as $person)
{
    echo $person['name'];
}
```

Comment: He wants to print the names of executive producers.

Comment: He wants to get indexes either. This will give him complete filtered array, then he could loop it or do whetever he wants.

Comment: If it involves two steps, you might as well just use a `foreach` ;)

Comment: Shorter doesn't mean better at all. If you using template system you should keep your logic in other place. What if he will need to display names more than one time? It will be inefficient (slow).